# how can make a SKSpriteNode follow another one SKSpriteNode that has a physics body

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Using swift, I am trying to make a `SKSpriteNode` (that doesn't have a physics body) follow another `SKSpriteNod`e that has a physics body. I want this to be done when there is contact between the sprite with a physics body and another physics body. I read about setting `SKContsraints` but these have a range and often fall out or vary. I want the sprite to be followed precisely. How can this be done?

Comment: What kind of effect do you want?  Do you want it to be like a stick is connecting them or do you want one of them to follow closely behind,ecentually hitting the sprite if it stays still?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your scene is a SKPhysicsContactDelegate. Then put this in your didBeginContact() method.

```
nodeWithoutPhysicsbody.position = nodeWithPhysicsbody.position
```

If you want the node without the physics body to always follow the node with the physics body, then put that line of code in the update method.